# why iam getting an error related to bind_result in error_log file and how to fix it?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Iam getting this error**

> [07-Sep-2017 11:48:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result():
>   Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared
>   statement

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where Id =?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['Id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt-> bind_result($Id);
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0) {
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$Taxname=$row['TaxName'];
$Tid=$row['Id'];
}}
```

Comment: What is the value you are getting in  `$Id`?

Comment: @Gunaseelan sir .i just need to know what should be the variable in bind_result? is the value comes from database ?

Comment: How many columns and what are all column values did you get in table name `table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter your query. Instead of `*` you need to instead opt for picking out the data you actually want from the database.
For example, if the table `table` has columns `Id,TaxName` then you would execute like so:

```
 <?php
 $sqlData = array();
 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Id,TaxName FROM table where Id =?");
 $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['Id']); //id is an integer? this should be i instead of s
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result(); //store the result, you missed this
 $stmt-> bind_result($Id,$TaxName); //bind_result grabs the results and stores in a variable
 $numRows = $stmt->num_rows; //see the correction I made here
 if($numRows >0){
      while ($stmt->fetch()) { //propper way of looping thru the result set
           $sqlData [] = array($Id,$TaxName);
           //assoc array would look like:
           //$sqlData [] = array("Id" =>$Id,"TaxName" => $TaxName);
      }
 }
 $stmt->close(); //close the connection
 ?>
```

Then you would have an array of results that you can use after you've finished with mysqli queries. 
Hope this helps you understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Id,TaxName FROM table where Id =?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['Id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt-> bind_result($Id,$TaxName);
$stmt->store_result();
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0) {

   while( $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
     $newid = $Id;
     $newtaxname= $TaxName;
   }
   print_r($newid)."<br>";
   print_r($newtaxname);
}
```

This code will give you the answer without any warnings.

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

> mysqli_stmt::bind_result — Binds variables to a prepared statement for
>   result storage

Comment: `$result = $stmt-> bind_result($Id,$TaxName);` from the documentation, `bind_result` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. He will get no errors/warnings because `$numRows` will always return 0

Comment: @WillParky93 I have updated the answer as `$stmt->num_rows` instead of `$result->num_rows`.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include `$stmt->store_result();`  before `$stmt->num_rows;` as we are making a `prepare` not a `query` and `num_rows` doesn't like prepare that much! In this instance, `num_rows` will return either 0 or an incorrect number